# Asking for more infos without being requested an interview now

Tags: interviewing, job-search

Maybe the title is not sugestive but the problem lays like this:

Currently I'm in the first semester of the university and stumbled upon a nice job spot on a company that creates video games. Creating videogames is my dream, and that's mostly what got me into programming.

The company that posted the announce say that are looking for Junior developers for videogames and I'm really curious to know more.

But I do not want to sound too interested, as there are still some things I have to repeat (like 3D Maths) before I can go to an interview. But still, I'd like to more know and even even get the chance to do Job-Shadowing, if offered now and and Internship in the summer.

Thus being said, what should I put down in the email I'm thinking of sending them? Firstly I wanted to ask if that offer is still up. But what more? What if they'll ask me to show up and by doing so, I'll destroy my chances in the future? Or should I even send them an email?

Comment: Why does it matter if the offer is still up, if you aren't fit for the job?

Comment: It is not that I am not fit for the job. I match the minimum requirements, but I want, because of the fear that one small mistake might end all my changes of getting hired.

Comment: I'm quite sure you'll not be the only one interested in this job, thus you should not try not to "sound too interested"... employers want to get highly interested and motivated people. I suggest you just apply for that job NOW and see how it goes. If they don't take you, you'll at least have learnt something for the next time you apply for a job.

Answer (score 2):

You may not be ready for the job, as you said, you have some classes to do over. First, you'll never get the job if you never ask for it. So, write an email explaining that you are in school and would like to work for them. They will not pay you as much since you are not completely ready for the job, but you might get it.

Second, if they say you are not ready, if you really want the job, stay in touch and build a rapport with them. Any hiring manager would rather hire a known quantity over an unknown. By staying in touch...every six months...send an inquiry into whether things have opened an opportunity.

Comment: Did you really mean 'quantity', or is it rather 'quality'? Quality would make more sense, imho.

Comment: I've never heard the phrase, "known quality" before,  but it makes sense. "Known quantity" is a common phrase meaning, "knowing what you are going to get."